# Finding elements in deep structures using Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nested

In the sample HTML page:

```
<tr class="highlight">
  <td><center><a href="example.code"> Bar </a></center></td>
  <td><center> Foo </center></td>
</tr>
```

How can I get the `innerHTML/text` of all `<td>`?

I have tried:

```
tabLevel = sel.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='highlight']")
tabLevel.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td")
tabLevel.get_attribute("text")
    for x in tabLevel.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td"):
    print(x)
```

the response:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e8e686b9-aed8-42bc-b8f6-9085d3c96d93", element="34ca0e67-0aeb-4dd5-8d99-4b50432ff16c")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e8e686b9-aed8-42bc-b8f6-9085d3c96d93", element="a77b4351-5128-4bbe-a937-f7cffe7bad43")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e8e686b9-aed8-42bc-b8f6-9085d3c96d93", element="dd6fef94-56f7-49e7-80e5-83e03f2e1b23")>
```

The wanted output (for `print(x)`) is something like:
`Bar Foo`

Answer (score 2):

```
print(x.text)
print(x.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

The first one prints the innerText and the second command prints the innerHTML